# Disabling tslint for a block of code with tslint:disable does not work

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, tslint

I'm trying to disable TSlint (Version: typescript 3.5.2, tslint 5.18.0) for a block of code in a VueJS project but it doesn't seems to work (it still displays errors and warning for this block at compilation with npm run serve)

I've already tried to use commented tslint:disable and eslint-disable without success.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I have faced same issue in my Angular project below is how I solved my problem.

```
  // tslint:disable
  (event.keyCode >= A && event.keyCode <= Z) ||
  (event.keyCode >= ZERO && event.keyCode <= NINE) ||
  event.keyCode === SPACE ||
  (this.preventHomeEndKeyPropagation &&
  (event.keyCode === HOME || event.keyCode === END))
  // tslint:enable
```

Answer (score 3):

The one way left:
use `// @ts-ignore` over every line you want to skip checking (i hope the block is not too large)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this doesn't work either... It seems like `npm run serve` invokes another linter than TSlint but I don't know which one nor do I know how to disable it for few lines

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable a specific rule for a block of code like that:

```
// tslint:disable:max-line-length
...your code here
// tslint:enable:max-line-length
```